# Forcing http on homepage using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using .htaccess to force https on certain pages and http on other pages and it's working fine. But I need to force http on home page `(example: http://website.com)` and I don't know how to do that. I tried `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/?` but as I'm using drupal that didn't work.

This is the script I'm using:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/register/? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/about-us/? [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/help/?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, instead of `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}`, you can use [`RewriteCond %{HTTPS}`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond), which should be more reliable in detecting HTTPS.

The homepage has the `RewriteRule` pattern `^$`. So the rule would be

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^$ http://website.com [R,L]
```

When everything works as you expect, you can change `R` to `R=301`.